# MySql Update on Duplicate (Unique) Key error

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a legacy php app with a MySql database.

There's a table with following in the app:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cards` (
    `score` smallint NOT NULL,
    `cardId` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    `probability` DECIMAL(20,19),
    `autoTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    KEY `autoTs`    (`autoTs`),
    UNIQUE KEY `score_ cardId` (`score`, `cardId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So the unique id is score_cardId because the probabilities for those will change over time.
Now I'm trying to insert new values for probability into that database table where I know there are unique keys however I just keep getting the same error from MySql:

`"Duplicate entry '600-cardKey1' for key 'score_ cardId'`

This is the code I have for the update; not sure what I need to change in order to update where there's a duplicate unique key:

```
INSERT INTO cards 
  (score, cardId, probability) 
 VALUES 
(600, 'cardKey1', 0.773360594), 
(543, 'cardKey2', 0.770445253);
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = VALUES(score), cardId = VALUES(cardId), probability = VALUES(probability);
```

Any ideas? I've tried a few different variations of "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".  This actually worked manually in SQL but I have too many rows to update manually so am wondering what 's going on.

Comment: You should know that `INSERT` is to create a new row of data. `UPDATE` is to change the values of an existing row of data. So obviously you get "duplicate entry" errors when you use INSERT to update existing rows. Also, please don't tag PHP when your question is purely MySQL related.

Comment: Yep; I know that. But from what I read of MySql, if this key already exists then we should update.  The problem is that the update function does not seem to work; though running it for just one of the error lines it does work.

Comment: @rl279 - Just remove ; before `ON DUPLICATE` and try..!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to update the probability, change the statement to:

```
INSERT INTO cards(score, cardId, probability) 
VALUES (600, 'cardKey1', 0.773360594), (543, 'cardKey2', 0.770445253)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE probability = VALUES(probability);
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo; I've tried that too but still end up with an error and no DB change.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ; before `ON DUPLICATE`

```
INSERT INTO cards 
(score, cardId, probability) 
 VALUES 
(600, 'cardKey1', 0.773360594), 
(543, 'cardKey2', 0.770445253) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE score = VALUES(score), cardId = 
VALUES(cardId), probability = VALUES(probability);
```